# How to enable git blame on every file in project in intelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, git-blame

I want to see git-blame on the side of the currently opened file on default. Currently i have to activate it per file i open. Is that possible with intelliJ?

I'm using GitToolBox, but it only shows it for the current file unlike the git blame option from intellij